# Fetch(): Request body malformed

Tags: javascript, json, fetch-api

I want to make a fetch request to an API that accepts different types of body requests: twitter handle, facebook link, phone number, etc. The structure of the body is:

```
body: {
    "typeOfHandle": "input"
}
```

Since there are different types of handles, I test the input type and assign it to the body accordingly, as seen below:

```
// handle is the input
let atSign = /^[@]/,    
    handleIsTwitter = atSign.test(handle.value),
    handleType;

handleIsTwitter ? handleType = `"` + "twitter" + `"` : console.log("not twitter");
let abc = `"` + handle.value + `"`;
let bodyOfFetch = `{${handleType}: ${abc}}`;
console.log("body: " + bodyOfFetch);
fetch("xxx", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        Authorization: "xxx"
        },
    body: JSON.stringify(bodyOfFetch)
    })
    .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
    })
    .then(function(json) {
        console.log(json);
    });
```

However, this method returns a `body malformed` error. When I do the request statically (i.e. replace the variables with static text, e.g. `"twitter": "@alex"`) it works. I double-triple-quadruple checked the syntax, I don't think that is the problem. Can it be an issue on the API's side?

Comment: Im not sure why you build the body as a template string.
Try building it as an object and pass it to JSON.stringify
`JSON.stringify({[handleType]: abc})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example `bodyOfFetch` is a string (`{"twitter": "@alex"}`). Either you can send it directly, this is:

```
fetch("xxx", {
method: "POST",
headers: {
    Authorization: "xxx"
    },
body: bodyOfFetch
})
```

Or you can send a stringify object:

```
fetch("xxx", {
method: "POST",
headers: {
    Authorization: "xxx"
    },
body: JSON.stringify({[handleType]: abc})
})
```

But sending `JSON.stringify(bodyOfFetch)` will stringify a json string, this will add surrounding `"` and escape existing quotation marks: `"{\\"twitter\\": \\"@alex\\"}"`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, the first solution did the trick! I didn't completely wrapped my mind around the explanation though: `bodyOfFetch`, at declaration time, isn't a JSON string, it's just a string. I get that if you stringify it, it will introduce new data into the string, but shouldn't that extra data (JSON formatting, let's call it) be read correctly by the API?

Comment: JSON.stringify of a string will produce the json representation of a string, not of an object. The json representation of a string `abc` is `"abc"`.

Comment: Also, in the second solution, you should remove the quotation marks from your values `handleType` and `abc`